# Credible sources for Rho-Rotation?

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, latin, greek, rhotics

A teacher of mine recently mentioned a phenomenon in linguistics called "rho-rotation". Across eons and languages if a r/rho sound was next to a vowel it tended to switch postitions and "jump" before or after the vowel. He named the example of the Ancient Greek "ἁρπάζειν" which turned into the Latin "rapere" (later in English "to rob" or German "rauben") all with the meaning "to take/rob/grab".

I have found this phenomenon described by other teachers and quite vaguely in some Latin textbooks but never in an actual linguistics book or paper, especially on the internet.

Do you know any sources of further information on this topic?

Comment: The exact origin of harpazō is unclear, but it's not the ancestor of Latin rapiō. For a more likely cognate of rapiō, look at ereptomai "pluck".

Comment: This is just a specific kind of metathesis. If you search for 'rhotic metathesis' (or something similar) you'll get lots of hits. BTW, English has quite a few instances of rhotic metathesis from Old English to Modern, eg brid->bird, thrid->third, hros->horse.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Thank you very much, I had never heard of the word metathesis before and it helped a lot.

Comment: @Draconis Interesting... English speaking web-etymology sites agree with you on the origin of rapere, but a lot of German dicionaries site ἁρπαζω. But that wasn´t my question anyway.

Comment: not relevant to this particular case, but Greek reflects PIE *r̥ (syllabic r) as "ra", where Latin has "or" so some instances of apparent metathesis (and a slightly different vowel) could just be different reflexes

Comment: Indo-European language histories are full of various kinds of "rhotacism", including r/l dissimilation, r/s alternation, r/l falling together and reseparating, etc. Liquids are more fluid than most consonants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you refer to as "rho-rotation" is just a specific kind of [metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)). If you search for "rhotic metathesis" (or something similar, perhaps "liquid metathesis" or "r-metathesis") you'll find plenty of discussion about this phenomenon.

English has quite a few instances of rhotic metathesis from Old English to Modern, for example

- brid->bird
- thrid->third
- hros->horse

Answer (score 5):

Yes, rhotic metathesis (or r-metathesis) is a real thing. If you want a recent-ish study on it, try [this 2013 paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024384113001940) by Bartłomiej Czaplicki.

Simply, metathesis is the transpositions of letters, sounds, or syllables within a word. You see it everywhere in many languages worldwide, and rhotic metathesis is no exception. In his comment to your question, Gaston mentions a few of the more well-known examples in English, and you do frequently see the phenomenon going from Latin to Old French, such as:

> turbulare -> turbler -> trubler (Eng. trouble)
> fimbria -> frimbia -> frenge (Eng. fringe)

While this principle is sound, it's not quite what happened with the verbs in question. First, no one knows exactly where *harpazein* comes from, but the initial *h-*, if it's IE and related to *harpe* (see [Beekes](https://brill.com/view/title/17726) on why that might not be the case), it would likely begin with initial *s-*. But this isn't for sure.

Now, people *used* to think that *harpazein* is cognate with *rapere*, but that's no longer current. ([LSJ](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da(rpa%2Fzw) includes it; Beekes mentions it at ἐρέπτομαι.) Regardless, both the Latin *rapere* and the German *rauben* (cognate with *rob*) do not directly descend from the Greek; they are derived more immediately from their parent languages. The Proto-Germanic [**raubōną*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/raub%C5%8Dn%C4%85) gives rise to the German *rauben* and the English *rob*. Both go back to PIE, with the initial letter being *hr*-.

If there is a Latin connection, Wiktionary points to **Hrewp-* being cognate with the Latin *rupes* ("cliff") and *rumpere* ("to shatter") (with a present nasal infix; past passive participle *ruptus*).

Following Draconis' comment, we do see a cognate with *rapere* in Greek's *ἐρέπτομαι*. This is a normal yod-present (or jot-present) derivation of the PIE ancestor. It is not the direct ancestor of the Latin *rapere* or the German/English *rauben/rob*.

To sum, yes, rhotic metathesis is real and there is plenty of evidence for it. No, that's not what's going on with these verbs. Crucially, though, *harpazein* does not give rise to *rapere* and (either directly or indirectly) *rauben* and *rob*.